# HTTP通信で情報を受け取る方法とその情報をwebサーバーのプログラムで処理する方法

Tags: python, python3

表記の件につきましてご教授願えればと存じます。
以下がプログラムのコードです。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

http_body='''<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
   <title>today's fortune</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 {month} is your birth month,today is {fortune} for you ! 
 </body>
 </html>'''

 #URLのパラメーターから、monthを取得（整数に変換）
param_data=cgi.FieldStorage()
month=int(parama_date.getvalue("month"))
today=datetime.date.today()

contents={}
contents["month"]=month
contents["fortune"]=["a happy day","a bad day","a brilliant day"]
[today.day*month%6]

print("Content-type:text/html")
print("")
print(http_body.format(**contents))
```

＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿

こちらをターミナル上で確認したところ以下のエラーが出ました。

```
The above is a description of an error in a Python program, formatted
     for a Web browser because the 'cgitb' module was enabled.  In case you
     are not reading this in a Web browser, here is the original traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fortune_month.py", line 20, in &lt;module&gt;
    month=int(parama_date.getvalue("month"))
NameError: name 'parama_date' is not defined
```

CGIに対応したwebブラウザに以下のURLを打ち込むと以下のようなエラーが返ってきました。

＜URL＞

`http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/fortune_month/py?month=8`

＜エラー＞

```
essage: No such CGI script ('/cgi-bin/fortune_month.py').
Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーメッセージから察するに、`parama_date.getvalue("month")` は `param_date.getvalue("month")` なのでしょうね、きっと。

Comment: 質問の際、タグで`python3`を指定してるのでタイトルに<python3>のような独自タグっぽい文字を入れるのは不要だと思います。

Comment: 作成されたプログラム `fortune_month.py` と、入力したURL `fortune_month/py?month=8` とでファイル名が一致していないようですので、こちらも確認してください。

Comment: -metropolis
ありがとうございます。修正いたしました。

Comment: -cubick 
タグの件承知しました。教えていただきありがとうございます。
またURLに関しましても修正いたしました。感謝です。

Comment: しかしながら依然としてエラーが出ます。
以下にエラーコードを記します。

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fortune_month.py", line 20, in &lt;module&gt;
    month=int(param_data.getvalue('month'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コマンドラインから実行するのであれば、`python3 fortune_month.py month=8` などとする必要があるのではないでしょうか。マニュアルを読むことをお勧めします。

Comment: -metropolis
ありがとうございます。コマンドラインからの実行はできました。webサーバー上でトライしています。現在「pythonスタートブック」を手元に励んでいますが、もう一度熟読いたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原因はすべてtypo(タイプミス)です。変数名も、

> param**a**_dat**e**

-> param_dat**a**

URLも。

> http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/fortune_month/py?month=8

-> http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/fortune_month.py?month=8

一致しなければならない箇所は、コピペするなどして、typoを回避するようにして下さい。

Comment: コードとURLを修正させていただきました。
実際にURLを打ち込んで見たところ、ちゃんとwebサーバーで表示されたのですが、リストの部分が右記のようにそのまま表示されてしまいました。8 is your birth month,today is ['a happy day', 'a bad day', 'a brilliant day'] for you !

Comment: それは、`contents["fortune"]=["a happy day","a bad day","a brilliant day"]`と`[today.day*month%6]`の間に改行があるからでしょう。配列[n]で配列のn番目の値が取得できます。加えて言うと、`%6`としていますが、6の剰余は0〜5なので、場合によっては配列外参照のエラーになります。何を意図して`%6`としたのかは私には分かりませんが、正しくは`%3`だと思われます。

Comment: 丁寧な解説ありがとうございます。無事に表示されました。